# Creating a List<> of a Subset of Keys and Strings in a .RESX file

Tags: c#

I have a `.resx` file that contains all the strings for my website.  I'd like to create a `List<string>` of a subset of these strings without having to use `add()` for each new string like this:

```
List<string> listOfResourceStrings= new List<string>();
listOfResourceStrings.Add(Resources.WebSite_String1);
listOfResourceStrings.Add(Resources.WebSite_String2);
listOfResourceStrings.Add(Resources.WebSite_String3);
listOfResourceStrings.Add(Resources.WebSite_String4);
listOfResourceStrings.Add(Resources.WebSite_String5);
listOfResourceStrings.Add(Resources.WebSite_Stringn);
```

I could use...

```
System.Resources.ResourceSet listOfResourceStrings = Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, true, true);
```

...but this returns a `ResourceSet` and contains **all** the strings.  And, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to find a subset of the strings.

Thank you for your help,

Aaron

Comment: Do you know what subset you want or do you determine that dynamically?

Comment: I'd like to say `find("Website_")` or something like that.  So, dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Resource data is stored in static properties, so reflection can be used to selectively extract the property values based on the property name.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
      var strings = GetStringPropertyValuesFromType(typeof(Properties.Resources), @"^website_.*");
      foreach (var s in strings)
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    public static List<String> GetStringPropertyValuesFromType(Type type, String propertyNameMask)
    {
      var result = new List<String>();
      var propertyInfos = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
      var regex = new Regex(propertyNameMask, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

      foreach (var propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
      {
        if (propertyInfo.CanRead &&
           (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(String)) &&
           regex.IsMatch(propertyInfo.Name))
        {
          result.Add(propertyInfo.GetValue(type, null).ToString());
        }
      }

      return result;
    }
  }
}
```